# SQL Server 2005 Update query not incrementing properly

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table that I need to increment the value by -1. Instead of incrementing happening I get -1 in all my updated columns. Any help is appreciated.

```
UPDATE rpt_FYInfo 
SET rptpddiff = rptpddiff - 1
WHERE rptpddiff =0 and UCI= 'BPA'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're making sure that all of the rptpddiffs are 0, then decrementing them by 1. Seems like you would want to do it to all your rptpddiffs unless you're expecting the -1 on all of them. (This is how you do -1,-2,-3,-4)

```
UPDATE rpt_FYInfo 
SET rptpddiff = rptpddiff - 1
WHERE UCI= 'BPA'
```

Unless you want them to stop at 0 or something, which case just change your logic to match.

To increment, just change your logic to, of course you probably want to know something about the entity you're updating, unless UCI is its primary key or something.

```
UPDATE rpt_FYInfo 
SET rptpddiff = rptpddiff + 1
WHERE UCI= 'BPA'
```

Comment: I have a primary key that is called rptpd. I have amended my code to try and use this field. The code is still not incrementing properly.

Comment: UPDATE rpt_FYInfo 
SET rptpddiff = rptpd - 378
WHERE rptpddiff = -1 and UCI= 'BPA'

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `rptpddiff` to -1 in your update statement where its initial value is 0.

Comment: You are correct. How would I change rptpddiff so I would get -1,-2,-3,-4,-5, and so on

Comment: are all the values of rptpddiff = 0?